# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, repository

Пытаюсь подключить удаленный репозитарий, который только что создал. Ошибка вот такая:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: с помощью команды `cd путь` сделайте текущим каталог, в котором находится под-каталог `.git` (в котором, собственно, и находится репозиторий (хранилище)), и там уже подключайте удалённое хранилище.

Comment: хотя есть подозрение, что вам нужно не «подключить» (`git remote add ...`), а **клонировать** хранилище (`git clone ...`).

Comment: Да, перешел в свой локальный каталог и от туда команда прошла. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы просмотреть список настроенных удалённых репозиториев, вы можете запустить команду git remote. Она выведет названия доступных удалённых репозиториев. Если вы клонировали репозиторий, то увидите как минимум `origin` — имя по умолчанию для исходного репозитория:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/schacon/ticgit
Cloning into 'ticgit'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 1857, done.
remote: Total 1857 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1857/1857), 374.35 KiB | 268.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (772/772), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd ticgit
$ git remote
origin
```

Вы можете также указать ключ -v, чтобы просмотреть адреса для чтения и записи, привязанные к репозиторию:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (push)
```

Если у вас больше одного удалённого репозитория, команда выведет их все. Например, для репозитория с несколькими настроенными удалёнными репозиториями в случае совместной работы нескольких пользователей, вывод команды может выглядеть примерно так:

```
$ cd grit
$ git remote -v
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (fetch)
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (push)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (fetch)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (push)
defunkt   https://github.com/defunkt/grit (fetch)
defunkt   https://github.com/defunkt/grit (push)
koke      git://github.com/koke/grit.git (fetch)
koke      git://github.com/koke/grit.git (push)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (push)
```

Это означает, что мы можем легко получить изменения от любого из этих пользователей. Возможно, что некоторые из репозиториев доступны для записи, и в них можно отправлять свои изменения, хотя вывод команды не даёт никакой информации о правах доступа.

Обратите внимание на разнообразие протоколов, используемых при указании адреса удалённого репозитория. Подробнее протоколы рассмотрены в главе [Установка Git на сервер](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80#_git_on_the_server).

Comment: замечательный ответ. жаль, что отвечает он не на заданный вопрос, а на какой-то другой.

Answer (score 1):

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

как и написано, ни в текущем каталоге, ни в одном из вышележащих не обнаружен собственно репозиторий (хранилище), который располагается (обычно) в каталоге `.git` (вариант — `.git` может быть и файлом, в котором содержится информация об актуальном местоположении хранилища).

вероятно, вы выполняете `git remote add ...` (или что-то подобное) в каталоге, который не является рабочей копией (*working directory/tree*) хранилища (иначе говоря: не содержит файла/каталога `.git` ни текущий каталог, ни один из вышележащих).

сделайте (с помощью команды `cd путь`) текущим нужный каталог, и там уже выполняйте нужную вам команду.